# Call MySql stored procedure from Powershell script

Tags: mysql, powershell

I have written a stored procedure in SQL Server to delete certain data. I want to execute this stored procedure from a PowerShell script. Could anyone tell me what will be the SQL adapter command for a `DELETE` query?

This is for a `SELECT` query:

```bsh
$SQLAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your subject and tags say "MySQL", but your question text says "SQL Server". Which of the two is it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$SqlConn.open()

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM your_table WHERE id ='abc'"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConn
$SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery

$SqlConn.Close()
```